# How Should I get all images(including full URL) from Dropbox using Dropbox Core API in android app?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I need to get all the images on Dropbox with its full URL(not only name) as I need to display images as a list in my android app.

I am using Dropbox core API and called API as following:

DropboxAPI.Entry existingEntry= mDBApi.metadata("/", 1000, null, true, null);

Using above I got all the files listed and also got its name but couldn't get full URL of each file.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what exactly you need to do, and if you actually need a URL, and if so, what kind of URL.

If you just need the content of the image files, you should use the [`getFile`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener)) or [`getFileStream`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getFileStream(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to access the actual file content and display it as desired.

If you actually need a direct URL to the file contents, you can use [`media`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#media(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) to get the URL. Note that these expire after four hours though.

If you need a longer-lived URL, e.g., for sharing, you can get the (preview) URL by using [`share`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#share(java.lang.String)). (You can also modify these links for other behaviors as shown [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201).)

Comment: I got the URL using media as you mentioned above.