# How to get the image content url from Dropbox without expiration?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to get the image URL from the Dropbox and I followed the below code from the documentation.

```
 try {
        Entry directory = dropboxApi.metadata("/", 1000, null, true, null);
        directory.mimeType = "image*//*";
        for (Entry entry : directory.contents) {
            DropboxAPI.DropboxLink link = dropboxApi.media(entry.path, false);
            if (link.url.contains(".jpeg") || link.url.contains(".png") || link.url.contains(".jpg"))
                files.add(link.url);
        }
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Based on this code I can get the image URL. But it is not working after hours.
In my scenario, I want to get the image URL and I will send it to server API. So when I retrieve other API, I will get the image URL, what I sent. Once I got the URL, just I want to set it to imageview.

I have verified this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105908/how-should-i-get-all-imagesincluding-full-url-from-dropbox-using-dropbox-core?rq=1). I got the different link by using `share` method. But I don't know how to set that into my ImageView, whereas by using media method I can get the URL and I can set it to ImageView.

Please can someone help me to solve this problem

If i make an Http request for share url then I am getting image name with download option.

[image]

I am getting 16 headers.

[image]

From this am not getting any clue. There is no header name contains Location.There is one content-piracy-policy which gives some url values combined. But it is also not relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Should I get all images(including full URL) from Dropbox using Dropbox Core API in android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105908/how-should-i-get-all-imagesincluding-full-url-from-dropbox-using-dropbox-core)

Comment: As noted in the other question you linked to, links from `media` do expire after four hours, but you can use the links from `share` instead, as long as you modify it per: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Comment: @Greg Iam getting the link https://db.tt/CvTlpNuJ by using share method. But when i load that in browser, am getting https://www.dropbox.com/s/kve56umra5yzn4g/aaaaa.jpeg?dl=0. My doubt is how do i get the above link ("https://www.dropbox.com/s/kve56umra5yzn4g/aaaaa.jpeg?dl=0") by using the first link. Please can you clarify that.

Comment: You'll need to "expand" that short link first, by making an HTTP request to it and getting the redirected URL from the response's `Location` header.

Comment: @Greg I never get any response if i make an http request. I have updated my question with postman screenshot. Please check it.

Comment: The screenshot you posted does show a successful response. It shows a 200 status code with a web page as the body and 16 headers.

Comment: @Greg Sorry for the mistake. Yes I can see the 16 headers. But none of the headers name and value gives me a url. I have attached the image. I have also checked by debugging the application. I am getting 46 headers. But does not looks relevant. Please check it.

Comment: It looks like Postman is already following the redirect for you. The `Location` header would be on the first response, but you're looking at the second one.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the patience. I can't understand about first response and second response.